# Luxon set proper culture for displaying timezone name correctly

Tags: javascript, luxon

I'm using Luxon in my JavaScript project to display human readable time:

```
dateTime.toLocaleString({
    year: "numeric",
    month: "short",
    day: "numeric",
    hour: "numeric",
    minute: "numeric",
    hour12: false,
    timeZoneName: 'short'
});
```

However, the timezone is being displayed as GMT-7, and the requirement is to display it as PST or PDT.

Could you please share any suggestions how this could be done?

Thank you.

Comment: [`short` should work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat). What timezone does your `dateTime` have?

Comment: Also, what's the locale? The Intl API doesn't necessarily have the string "PST" for every locale